# SSIS How to pass variable/row count from one data flow process to another in the same control flow

Tags: variables, ssis, rowcount

Sorry I am new to SSIS. Using Visual Studio 2017.  In my SSIS package, in my Control Flow screen, I have just one Data Flow Task rectangle, that I labeled Appointments. When you click on that, you are taken to the Data Flow tab, where really everything happens here. I have two different processes or paths here. So for Path 1, I have a OLE DB Source. This runs a SQLSelect statement that pulls data from some tables off a SQL Server.  Then there is a green connector from this to a Row Count transformation rectangle, and then there is a green connector from that to a Flat File Destination rectangle. The Flat File destination is set up to get the output from the SQL statement, create a file on my hard drive, and put the results of the Select statement into that file. I call this file a “data” file. That is it for this process. My hope is to somehow save the record count of the Select statement. Now, on the same tab, I have another process we will call Path 2. I have an OLE DB Source. In this source, I have a SQL Select statement that just creates one record with 6 fields. All the fields are hard coded except one. This field is called RecordCount. So what needs to dynamically go into this field, is the row count from Path 1 (for now, I just have it hard coded to zero). I have a green connector from this OLE DB Source that goes to a Flat File Destination rectangle. This destination is set up to get the output from the (mostly) hard coded SQL statement, create a file on my hard drive, and put that one record into it. I call this file a “control” file. I have 3 connection managers created, one that connects to the SQL Server, and one for each Path on this tab. How can I get the row count from the first Path into the field in the file created by the second Path? I have tried several possibilities and have googled until I am blue in the face, but I cannot get anything to work. Being a newbie, I hesitate to tell you what all I have tried – so feel free to suggest anything, assume I know nothing. Keep in mind that I may in the future create a Path 3 and a Path 4 on the same tab, where the row count from Path 3 goes to Path 4 (don’t want to be using here the rowcount value from Path 1) – how will this affect things? Or would I need Path 3 and Path 4 to be related to a new Data Flow Task on the Control Flow screen?

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

The Row Count transformation requires an SSIS Variable. Double click it and see what value you put in there, something like `@User::Variable`

When the data flow finishes, the value of that variable will contain the number of rows that passed through the component.

That is all that you want in your data flow. The secondary path you describe, you will want to add that to a *new* data flow. Draw an On Completion arrow from Data Flow 1 to Data Flow 2. And the same for your future steps 3 and 4. Make the Dataflow focus on solving a single business problem (Export Sales to Text file).

Now that the first data flow has completed, the value of the SSIS variable will contain a value so you're going to use that in Data Flow 2 to write your one row of data to a text file.

In your OLE DB Source, you'll use a parameter like

```
DECLARE @RowCount int = ?;
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate, 'SalesExport' AS ExportType, @RowCount AS ExportCount;
```

That `?` is the placeholder for an OLE DB Parameter and if you click the Parameters button, you'll be able to specify that parameter `0` maps to `@User::Variable`

[image]

When that runs, you'll get a flat file with your one row of data and the actual value computed in data flow 1.

Lather, rinse, repeat the pattern for your exports. Do create an SSIS variable for each row count you need to keep track of so `@User::CountSales`, `@User::CountConsumers`, `@User::CountProviders` so that way you don't run into trouble later by re-using a variable before you were ready.

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly @billinkc. I followed your steps.I have the 2nd process as a new flow on the control flow screen. In the OLE DB Source, I have the line of code ? AS RecordCount. When I click on the Parameters button, I get an error message saying "Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL Command..." I do have a variable created  and it is User::RecordCount. I have it as a int32. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @maxwell2323 Good catch, didn't realize the inability to determine data type would be a problem. I have updated the TSQL to supply a typed variable which allows the Set Query Parameter box to work as expected.

Comment: thanks...I am making progress. I followed the steps again.But when I run the package, I get errors. The process does create the flat file, and gives me a header row. But that is all it does not display the one record. I will try to display the error statements - if I can figure out how to copy an image here.

Comment: Okay the image won't copy over (of course) so I will have to type out the error line I see.   ole DB Source Historical Appointments Control [20]] error: There was an error with OLE DB source Historical Appointments Control.Outputs [OLE DB Source Output].Columns [RecordCount]" failed because truncation occurred...

Comment: Let me know your thoughts @billinkc

Comment: Edit your original post to get the error in there. Given the error `failed because truncation occurred` you will want to check the field definitions. Seems odd that the source would be reporting it, but no matter.

Comment: Also, it never hurts to have a trivial SSIS project sitting around so that you can make trivial reproductions. Were it me, I'd have a package with a Variable named `User::RecordCount` and then add a Data Flow with an OLE DB Source, pointed to any SQL Server instance and use the supplied query with parameterization and then direct that to an empty Derived Column component. Hit F5 and see whether it works. If so, then it's a matter of finding out the difference between my repro and the actual project. If not, then it's a Q of how my version differs from the supplied sample

Comment: I was able to add the link to the error image in my original post

Comment: Hey I solved it, but would not have been able to do it w/o your help.So additionally, I set the data type of the RecordCount variable to int64. Then in the second process, in the OLE DB Source, in the Advance Editor > Input and Output properties, for the RecordCount column - in both the external columns and input columns - make sure the datatype is four byte unassigned integer. Now it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to add additional logging to some new SSIS packages.

Part of this logging is to include row counts for data flow tasks performed in separate containers and then a total row count across all containers.

I would imagine there is a way to do math with variables at different trigger points, but I couldn't determine how to do this (yet).  Other answers on the net might not be clear to any successors of mine.  So here is what I did for those that might need to do the same thing:

**Create generic variables to use between containers:**

**[User::processrowcount]** - Each data flow task in each container captures the row count coming from the data source.  The Row Count assigns its value to this variable.

**[User::insertedrowcount]** - Each data flow task in each container captures the row count going to the final data destination.  The Row Count assigns its value to this variable.

**[User::totalprocessedrowcount]** - This will hold the sum of all previous [User::processedrowcount]s.  This value is set by an Execute SQL Task.

**[User::totalinsertedrowcount]** - This will hold the sum of all previous [User::insertedrowcount]s. This value is set by an Execute SQL Task.

Each container has a data flow task resembling the **Data Flow Task Screenshot** below to illustrate where Row Counts are captured (and assigned to their respective variables).

**Add an Execute SQL Task to each (import) Container:**
For each (import) Container add an Execute SQL Task.  I parameterize virtually anything that I can, including Data Source Connections so mine all share the same connection.

For parameters, I add a trio per row count that I want to sum/track:

1. OUTPUT variable [User::totalprocessedrowcount], parameter name 0
2. INPUT variable [User::processedrowcount], parameter name 1
3. INPUT variable [User::totalprocessedrowcount], parameter name 2
4. OUTPUT variable [User::totalinsertedrowcount], parameter name 3
5. INPUT variable [User::insertedrowcount], parameter name 4
6. INPUT variable [User::totalinsertedrowcount], parameter name 5

Then the SQLStatement should contain a SET per row count I want to sum/track.  The sum uses the trio of parameters I defined above:

```
SET ? = ? + ?;
SET ? = ? + ?;
```

I later used the [User::totalprocessrowcount] in the final Log Stats (Execute SQL Task) to log final operation stats.  See **Log Sample Screenshot** for an example.

That's it.

---

**Data Flow Task Screenshot**:
[image: Data Flow Task Screenshot]

**Variables Screenshot**:
[image: Variables Screenshot]

**Control Flow and Containers Screenshot**:
[image: Control Flow and Containers Screenshot]

**Import Container Execute SQL Task Screenshot**:
[image: Import Container Execute SQL Task Screenshot]

**Log Sample Screenshot**:
[image: Log Sample Screenshot]